# Efficiency of SELECT queries SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

My friend and I tried to build an advanced model for soccer pools betting. Due to limitations in Excel we found SQL to be a better choice going forward. We've managed to achieve what we were aiming for but the process takes around 20-30 minutes each time which I think it because of the inefficiency in the process. I'll try to explain what we are doing and hopefully you smart guys can point me in the right direction to do a more efficient approach.

So let's start to show you how the SQL-database looks like. We got one main table, `Rows`, which contains all possible combinations of game outcomes for 13 soccer matches:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rows](
[RowID] [int] NULL,
[Match_1] [int] NULL,
[Match_2] [int] NULL,
[Match_3] [int] NULL,
[Match_4] [int] NULL,
[Match_5] [int] NULL,
[Match_6] [int] NULL,
[Match_7] [int] NULL,
[Match_8] [int] NULL,
[Match_9] [int] NULL,
[Match_10] [int] NULL,
[Match_11] [int] NULL,
[Match_12] [int] NULL,
[Match_13] [int] NULL
);

INSERT INTO Rows
    (RowID, Match_1, Match_2, Match_3, Match_4, Match_5, Match_6, Match_7, Match_8, Match_9, Match_10, Match_11, Match_12, Match_13) 
VALUES 
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3),
(3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2),
(4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1),
(5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3),
(6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2),
(7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1),
(8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3),
(9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
(10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1);
```

So this amounts to around 1,6 million rows. The values stand for 1=Home victory, 3=Draw, 2=Away victory.

Now we need to select which ones are likely be the outcome for the current week. We use Excel to have our data and track which conditions to be used. Excel populates SQL-queries with the numbers adjusted for each gameweek so we just copy and paste into SQL Server Management Studio. We have around 1300 conditions which we test and apply approximately 600-700 every week. To be able to add the data for these 13 specific games we use computed columns. So we add around 700 computed columns to the table. Example:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Rows ADD Group1 AS ((CASE WHEN [Match_1] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_1] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_1] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_2] = 1 THEN 1 WHEN [Match_2] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_2] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_3] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_3] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_3] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_4] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_4] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_4] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_5] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_5] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_5] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_6] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_6] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_6] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_7] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_7] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_7] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_8] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_8] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_8] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_9] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_9] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_9] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_10] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_10] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_10] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_11] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_11] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_11] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_12] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_12] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_12] = 2 THEN 0 END) + (CASE WHEN [Match_13] = 1 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_13] = 3 THEN 0 WHEN [Match_13] = 2 THEN 0 END));
```

So basically what this does is to, with help of the CASE-expression, calculate how many of the desired outcomes each row has. For `Group1` we only want exactly one game which you will see in the SELECT query below.

The last step (which is the one which takes the majority of the time) is to `SELECT` all rows which fulfils all our requirements. It uses as previously said approx 700 different conditions so we have to split it into several queries using `WITH`-clauses.

```
WITH Step1 AS (
SELECT [Rows].[RowID],[Rows].[Match_1],[Rows].[Match_2],[Rows].[Match_3],[Rows].[Match_4],[Rows].[Match_5],[Rows].[Match_6],[Rows].[Match_7],[Rows].[Match_8],[Rows].[Match_9],[Rows].[Match_10],[Rows].[Match_11],[Rows].[Match_12],[Rows].[Match_13]
FROM Rows
WHERE [Rows].[Group1] >= 1 AND [Rows].[Group1] <= 1
)
SELECT [Step1].[RowID],[Step1].[Match_1],[Step1].[Match_2],[Step1].[Match_3],[Step1].[Match_4],[Step1].[Match_5],[Step1].[Match_6],[Step1].[Match_7],[Step1].[Match_8],[Step1].[Match_9],[Step1].[Match_10],[Step1].[Match_11],[Step1].[Match_12],[Step1].[Match_13]
INTO FinalRows
FROM Step1
;
```

Where should I look to simplify this and gain efficiency? Do you have any suggestions for me going forward? The ideal would be to achieve start to finish on 5-10 minutes max.

Comment: Looks like you have some major denormalisation issues here. There should be a single `Match` column, not 13.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So it's best suited to concat Match_1-Match_13 as a single column, am I right?

Comment: No, 1 row per match. I suggest reading up on Normal Form. A good design should be at least adhering up to [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around what you are trying to do - conceptually I think you've gone overboard. I'm not entirely sure from your question but here's my take on what I think you have: you want to bet on pools based on the most likely outcome between the teams involved in the 13 matches you get - you have some historic data which represents results between the matched teams and you want to cross-reference this to get the most likely outcome for the current week (essentially playing the odds). Does that sound right? If not, what data are you using as the driver to determine your bets?

Comment: I don't get the point of entering 3^13 rows into the database in the first place - surely you want a database schema that says `Home Team, Away Team, Result` and then enter your historic data and just query this using the home/away team? I don't get how pools can have "advanced" modelling when it's basically just a simple odds game.

Comment: @OldSport, it is generally best to design a relational data model following a [database normalization process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A relational model provides flexibility and RDBMS products like SQL Server are optimized for such designs (atomic elements without repeating data).

Comment: Yes Charleh, you are quite right in what we are aiming to do.

Comment: @OldSport ok, I mean, I don't see the point - there's no profit scheme from pools betting - such is the nature of sport. Essentially though, you just want a simple schema to track your results, you don't need to track "desirable outcomes", your query is what should do this. The combinations of possible outcomes are not data - they are odds. Your schema should be `Date, Home Team, Away Team, Result (you can use 1/2/3 here)`, this would represent the data set to drive your odds calculation. Is your model any more complex than just "the most common result between those teams"?

Comment: Once you've got your historic data in - you now have the ability to determine things from it - such as "if team X played team Y, what's the most common result", and then cross-reference that against your current 13 matches (13 queries, or one query with 13 sub-queries, whatever works for you). This would be almost instantaneous - however, it's assuming you don't have any sort of complex logic behind your model.

Comment: Ok, I think we've missunderstood eachother @Charleh. There is in Denmark a famous sports pool bettinggame called Tips 13 (https://danskespil.dk/tips/tips13?intcmp=topnav_tip_spilotips_spiltips13#/tps/poolid/1005845). The participants guess the outcome of 13 matches and share the prize pool if they get 13, 12, 11 and/or 10 right outcomes for their played rows.

Our database in SQL has ALL possible outcomes of these 13 games. We have the historical tracking in Excel and add the currenct weeks data in computed columns, then SELECT all rows which fulfill our conditions (approx 20k of 1,6 mill).

Comment: @OldSport yep, we are talking about the same thing. You want to play the odds, so to play the odds you need to use a model to determine the likely outcome. Your data is the historic information about existing results, your query is your model. You don't need to put 3^13 rows that represent the possible outcomes into your database then create 700 computed columns. That makes very little sense.

Comment: So whats you suggestion moving forward?

Comment: What I already said - you have historic results and you want to use these to work out the most likely outcome right? Your data is your historic results, not the possible outcomes. The possible outcomes are not data, they are odds. Put your data into your database and then query the data. It sounds like you are using Excel for data and SQL to store the logic ... as data?? I can't see a query taking more than 1 second for this even with hundreds of thousands of rows if you normalise and store your data and ask the correct questions.

Comment: OK so I have stored 3^13 in SQL. Conditions are for example, the sum of the other pool betters % in different outcomes where we want our rows to be in the range as prior game weeks where the data on several parameters are similair to current week. We want the number of 1,3,2 to be in similar range. When it comes odds we compare the ranking of the odds with prior game weeks and test the likelihood of specific rankings to be within different ranges and only apply conditions above a certain threshold. I'm just trying to understand how to design the data and perform the query. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR;

Use `PERSISTED` computed columns, also check the *execution plan* for hints on where you can optimise your query or data structures.

---

> There are far more efficient ways to do this, the first change you should consider is storing *ALL* the results into the SQL database, it looks like you have only modelled the outcomes over the entire pool for a single round.
>
> > I and other commenters have question the validity of such a model, especially when the additional meta-data like team identity, current position on the ladder, previous win loss ration for the season or against the same team are not taken into account. By storing the data such that you only record the results of each match additional insights can be gained and used when or if needed in your betting application.

> In Australia we simply call this "Tipping", everyone has a go designing something like this at some point, you will find out that simply from the raw results of each round you can write efficient set-based queries to come up with all sorts of derivative models. You might not even go back to excel for data management, and instead only use it for data visualization...

The first inefficiency is that the data is not all in the database, or if it is, it is not stored in an efficient manner. With simple indexes you should be able to get very efficient queries over many millions of records. 1.6 Million rows with only 14 columns is not a very big record set. Its not small, but you should still expect sub-second response on standard hardware for simple queries. 700 columns, thats a lot of data, but if the columns are defined as `TINYINT` then storage is not a big deal and you should still get very fast results.

But it sounds like your excel sheet is generating a batch of individual queries. There is a cost imposed simply for establishing the connection, parsing the query and returning the results, this is sometimes insignificant for a single query, but if you are issuing many queries then this handshaking and transmission cost can add up. You should try to alter the individual queries into more of a set-based query.

- This again is much easier if *ALL* of the data you have in Excel is migrated into SQL Server, or at least the raw results for each match of each historic round.

The next obvious efficiency to be gained is with `PERSISTED` computed columns. If you do not persist the values of the computed column, then for every query, and every evaluation within that query the computed column value needs to be resolved, if your 700 columns are computed, then thats a lot of work for the server to re-calculate the same value.

> Follow [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) for how to create `PERSISTED` computed columns:
>
> ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD RetailValue AS (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice * 1.5) PERSISTED

*It might be that this is the first change you can make that has significant impact. This offloads the computation to the `INSERT` command, and it adds a storage footprint, but you will experience must greater *read* throughput, one might even suggest at least a 700% increase.*

The last change is in your CTE query, you have not demonstrated any need for a CTE or nested query, SQL server will probably optimise that away anyway, do not be fooled into thinking that CTE's are cached results of a sub-query, that is not how they are implemented under the hood. But that is out of the scope of this post so just use this to return you final results:

```
SELECT [Rows].[RowID],[Rows].[Match_1],[Rows].[Match_2],[Rows].[Match_3],[Rows].[Match_4],[Rows].[Match_5],[Rows].[Match_6],[Rows].[Match_7],[Rows].[Match_8],[Rows].[Match_9],[Rows].[Match_10],[Rows].[Match_11],[Rows].[Match_12],[Rows].[Match_13]
INTO FinalRows
FROM Rows
WHERE [Rows].[Group1] >= 1 AND [Rows].[Group1] <= 1
```

---

#### A Note about Efficiency

When you want to troubleshoot query performance, the *first* place to check is the `Actual Execution Plan`,  you can also review the *Expected* execution plan, which might give you some pointers, but the *Actual* will give you results of the real plan that was used to resolve the query. For long running queries you will be able to visually identify the bottle-necks, then you can post back to SO or https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot, now it runs smoother.